1970s or earlier sci fi comic (possibly an anthology) that I had in the 1970's
In it was a story about an astronaut who is sent to the edge of the galaxy only to find there is an invisible barrier there like being inside of a fishbowl.
As I can't recall if it was in fact an anthology, there may have also been a WWII story where an American GI has a premonition about being pierced through the heart by a large caliber projectile (maybe a tank round?) only to have it happen at the end.
This was in the mid to late 1970's and the comic was an old, torn up relic even then. I can't recall a cover or any other details.

The comic Weird War Tales may be what you encountered.
